# using google maps api in a windows form application

Tags: c#, google-maps

I am making windows based application where I do a lot of data processing and end up with list of coordinates and other information. I would like to use to plot markers, routes etc on a google map.

I believe that the google api is meant for web based applications.

I would like to keep the solution desktop based since that framework is best suited to do all the data processing I want.

Is there a clean, non third party based solution to use google maps and the api to do drawing and marking on the map from within the .net application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GreatMaps` GMap.NET control for Microsoft's platforms.

it is across platform, open source .NET control  from Microsoft.
check the below link to understand how to use `GMap.Net` control

[GMap.NET Control](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/)

Comment: from Microsoft?? :O
really?? would you like to correct that?